# Mac Mini 2014 hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, mac-mini, flash-memory

Do the Mini 2014 mechanical hard-drive versions have an M.2 ssd slot on their mainboard?

EDIT: Let me clarify: the fusion version have a M.2 SSD on the mainboard slot and a 2.5" mechanical drive. Will I find this M.2 slot even on the mechanical-only version?

I'm referring to both 1.4 and 2.6 GHz versions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think no, as reported here in [this guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Mac+Mini+Late+2014+SSD+Replacement/32646) for replacing the SSD only the SSD or Fusion Drive version has the M.2 slot:

> Use this guide to replace the SSD stick in an SSD only, or Fusion Drive model of the Mac Mini Late 2014.

By the way you can easily figure out this opening the enclosure on the bottom following the guide linked before.

Comment: Dumb question, but could you not buy a 2014 Mini with a standard SATA hard disk and later add an M.2 SSD, thereby getting dual drives?

Comment: See answer above: I think no, you can't add M.2 SSD because probably it won't have the required slot.

Answer (score 1):

People are saying that all 2014 Mini have the connector for PCIe, but the HD-only models are missing the flex cable that has the SSD slot on the other end. Read this thread:

http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/apple-pcie-flex-cable-part-number-for-mac-mini-2014.1807145

I using an SSD-less Mac Mini at work, and personally I'm waiting for OWC to offer an upgrade product before putting in a purchase request, to be more confident it will come with the complete set of screws, screwdrivers, documentation to minimize my downtime. If it was my own machine & my own time, I'd follow this thread closer and try picking up some parts off ebay etc.